# Make Circle bigger jython?

Tags: jython, geometry, jes, timelapse

I'm trying to figure out how to make a time lapse video of a circle getting bigger and changing colour on jython, I was doing it and basically I kept doing getOval and putting new parameters each time but that is going to take me forever. I think I have to do something with for loops but I'm not sure how to go about it, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a for loop and use setAllPixelsToAColor(white) at the beginning of each iteration to "refresh" the drawing between frames.

Use the range() function to create a sequence of numbers you can use for radius values for your circle as you iterate through the loop.